# Is there any documentation on Custom Prompts with Adaptive Cards?

Tags: node.js, botframework, adaptive-cards

Is there any documentation or example in NodeJS on how to use and create a custom prompt? I am specially looking at how to consume adaptive cards in a prompt so that we could implement it into the waterfall dialogs.

Thanks,
Pranav

Comment: Are you using BotBuilder V3 or V4?

Comment: @KyleDelaney - I am currently using V3. But I see that V4 just went into GA so are open to use that as well depending on whether this feature could be achieved or not.

Comment: Could I get a little more information about what you're trying to achieve? I'd like to make sure you're aware of the various [types of prompts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-prompts?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript#prompt-types) already available to you. A choice prompt for example will automatically generate a card with buttons the user can click. Is that the kind of thing you would want to do with your card or is there something else?

Comment: Hi did you ever resolve this issue?